# awsインスタンスkubernetes環境を構築したいのですがエラーでつまります。

Tags: aws, docker, kubernetes

awsインスタンスkubernetes環境を構築したいのですが、

[Kubernetesでクラスタ環境構築手順(1) - masterの作成 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Esfahan/items/db7a79816731e6aa5cf5)
[【AWS】 EKS on Fargate のクラスタを構築してみる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/nabeatsu/items/8ec9895bfe90c18b13af)

上記のURLを参考にkubectlをダウンロードし、///配下に設置。
kubectl versionでインストールを確認まではうまくいったのですが、
kubectlでpodを作成したのですが下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

kubectlでクラスタは作れそうにないので、
eksctlをインストールしてクラスタを作ろうと下記のコマンド
を実行したのですが下記のようなエラーが出ます。
下記で出ているようなエラーの原因と解決策が解る方いましたらよろしくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーは `AlreadyExistsException` で `ekstest-cluster` は既に存在している様です。また、`eksctl completion bash ...` の部分もエラーになっていて、記事では `eksctl completion bash >> ~/.bash_completion` となっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kubectlは存在するKubernetesクラスターと対話するためのコマンドラインツールなのでkubectlでクラスターを作成することはできません。

eksctlはEKS(AWSのマネージドKubernetes)を管理するコマンドラインツールなので、EKSクラスターを作成することはできても、Kubernetesクラスターそのものを作成することはできません。

もしAWSのEC2上でKubernetesクラスターを作成したいのであれば、以下リンクを参考にkubeadmで作成することをお勧めします。

https://kubernetes.io/ja/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

また、eksctlやkubectlはサーバー上で作業するためのコマンドではなく、どちらかというと手元のローカル環境からKubernetes環境を管理するためのコマンドです。

ちなみに、エラー内容はCloudFormationのStackがすでに存在するというエラーなので、一度CloudFormationでクラスターのStackを削除して再度実行すれば成功するものと思われます。

Comment: ちなみにVMに入れたk8sでクラスタを作ろうとすると以下のようなエラーが出ます。Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.1.10:8443: i/o timeout

Comment: inductor様 ご丁寧に回答ありがとうございます。
感謝です。